# Wrong number of arguments thrown by rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, bundler

I'm trying to run a migration wi but I keep getting an error message.

We tried deleting the contents of the migration, only leaving the following :

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change      
  end
end
```

Which still causes the error message:

```
$ be rake db:migrate
== 20160619232005 CreateUsers: migrating ======================================
-- create_table(:users)    -> 0.0042s
== 20160619232005 CreateUsers: migrated (0.0043s) =============================

rake aborted! 
  StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) 
/home/ericmarche/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/bundle:22:in `load' 
/home/ericmarche/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>' ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) 
/home/ericmarche/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/bundle:22:in `load' 
/home/ericmarche/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>' Tasks: TOP => db:migrate (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: What version of `Ruby on Rails`, `Ruby` and `Bundler` are you using?

Comment: `Rails 4.2.0.beta2 `


`Bundler version 1.12.5 `


`ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]`

Answer (score 0):

You could delete the entire thing using:

```
rails d model user
```

then recreate it and then try re-migrating:

```
rails g model user
rake db:migrate
```

OR

you could go to the rails console and drop the users table and re-migrate

```
rails c #-> to go to the console
ActiveRecord::Migration.drop_table(:users) #-> to delete users table
exit #-> to exit console
```

and then try remigrating the table

Comment: Doesn't work. I tried creating a fresh project, generating a new model and then following up with `be rake db:migrate` and it throws the same exception.

Comment: what is that "be" before the rake for, could you try ommiting it when running the command

Answer (score -1):

why you are running migration with `be rake db:migrate` 
what `be` mean.

run migration in your project directory without `be` like `rake db:migrate`

Ex.:

```
$cd workspace/project

workspace/project$ rake db:migrate
```

Comment: be most likely an alias to `bundle exec`

Answer (score -1):

Did you try creating a new project and run

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```